# CodeIgniter clone database

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I clone a database in CodeIgniter? 
Currently I have this databases:

```
clockin_admin
clockin_template
```

The database `clockin_template` is the one I want to clone, with a different name. Is there any function to do this? I can't find it on documentation.

I'm currently creating the new database this way:

```
$this->load->dbforge();
$this->dbforge->create_database('clockin_' . randomStr());
```

Comment: Yes I did, but the solution was not by codeigniter. The solution was to talk to my server host and they pointed me into the right direction. In this case, my server host has a CPanel, and CPanel has developed a PHP XML-API in order to do lots of things to your databases such as: create new ones; delete; etc. https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php